# MySQL server keeps crashing every few minutes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I am having the hardest time tracking down this problem.

Every few minutes or so my database server crashes so all 3 WordPress sites on my WHM cPanels all crash at the same time. When it does, I get the following errors on phpMyAdmin. [image: error reporting]

My status monitor also looks like this:
[image: status graphs]

Just before the crash the numbers look like:

```
Questions: 910
Connections: 30
Processes: 26
Bytes sent: 59.6 MiB
Average load: 100%
Buffered memory: 1.2 GiB
Cached memory: 562.6 MiB
Free memory: 77.3 MiB
Cached swap: 25.9 MiB
Used swap: 164.2 MiB
Free swap: 833.9 MiB
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

**Edit:** As per [JYOTI RAJAI](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/171819/jyoti-rajai)'s comment, I tracked down the logs. For yesterday I had over 60,000 instances of this error message:

```
2020-06-04T19:06:51.057890Z 68060 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './<database>/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Then this started happening:

```
2020-06-04T19:06:51.995679Z 68061 [Note] Found 628 of 627 rows when repairing './<database>/wp_options'
2020-06-04T19:07:45.832221Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-06-04T19:07:45.835576Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 19188 ...
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868881Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868885Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868889Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-04T19:07:45.868893Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-06-04T19:07:45.870568Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-04T19:07:45.874033Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-06-04T19:07:45.877335Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 52M, instances = 1, chunk size = 52M
2020-06-04T19:07:45.893666Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-04T19:07:45.902361Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-06-04T19:07:45.920678Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-06-04T19:07:45.926440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 187614470
2020-06-04T19:07:45.926465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 187622785
2020-06-04T19:07:45.928429Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-06-04T19:07:45.928444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-06-04T19:07:45.996699Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
2020-06-04T19:07:45.997811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2020-06-04T19:07:46.183292Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-04T19:07:46.183331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-04T19:07:46.183398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-04T19:07:46.224593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.225793Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.225824Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.226142Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-04T19:07:46.276311Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 187622785
2020-06-04T19:07:46.277779Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.279417Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-04T19:07:46.294519Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200604 12:07:46
2020-06-04T19:07:46.295492Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.295506Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.298040Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.298098Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.299492Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-06-04T19:07:46.299534Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.299554Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-06-04T19:07:46.299560Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-04T19:07:46.360571Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-06-04T19:07:46.365364Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-06-04T19:07:50.924930Z 3 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './<database>/wp_redirection_404.MYI'; try to repair it
2020-06-04T19:07:50.924962Z 3 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './<database>/wp_redirection_404.MYI'; try to repair it
2020-06-04T19:07:50.924967Z 3 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table './<database>/wp_redirection_404.MYI'; try to repair it
2020-06-04T19:07:50.924971Z 3 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=3, /export/home2/pb2/build/sb_1-38465026-1584986589.6/rpm/BUILD/mysql-5.7.30/mysql-5.7.30/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:232
2020-06-04T19:07:50.924976Z 3 [ERROR] MySQL thread id 3, OS thread handle 140419102160640, query id 527 localhost <username> update
INSERT INTO `wp_redirection_404` (`url`, `created`, `ip`, `agent`) VALUES ('/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml', '2020-06-04 19:07:50', '67.207.43.162', 'Microsoft Office/14.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Microsoft Outlook 14.0.7248; Pro)')
2020-06-04T19:08:00.600440Z 24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './<database>/wp_redirection_404' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
... ( repeat single line above 54 times ) ...
2020-06-04T19:08:46.589575Z 79 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './<database>/wp_redirection_404' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
... ( repeat single line above 1848 times ) ...
```

The reboot sequence kept happening every few minutes.
I uninstalled the WordPress plugin that included the table `wp_redirection_404` before asking this question because the crashes kept happening. But that part of the log looks like this:

```
2020-06-05T01:31:32.534229Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 19731 ...
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594714Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594773Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594781Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594788Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-05T01:31:32.594800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-06-05T01:31:32.595445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-05T01:31:32.595713Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-06-05T01:31:32.599173Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 52M, instances = 1, chunk size = 52M
2020-06-05T01:31:32.609154Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-05T01:31:32.611283Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-06-05T01:31:32.656917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-06-05T01:31:32.680961Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 188393877
2020-06-05T01:31:32.680980Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 188393886
2020-06-05T01:31:32.680989Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-06-05T01:31:32.680994Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.418849Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-05T01:31:33.418872Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-05T01:31:33.418911Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-05T01:31:33.437853Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.438830Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.438856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.439142Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-05T01:31:33.496447Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 188393886
2020-06-05T01:31:33.496732Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.509354Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-05T01:31:33.522014Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.522028Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.546564Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.546668Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.559840Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200604 18:31:33
2020-06-05T01:31:33.581455Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-06-05T01:31:33.581504Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-06-05T01:31:33.581530Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-06-05T01:31:33.581535Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-05T01:31:34.139900Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-06-05T01:31:34.140388Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-06-05T01:37:46.181017Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-06-05T01:37:46.182802Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 21146 ...
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190432Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190480Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190795Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-05T01:37:46.190921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-06-05T01:37:46.192518Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 52M, instances = 1, chunk size = 52M
2020-06-05T01:37:46.195871Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-05T01:37:46.197148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-06-05T01:37:46.223869Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.229362Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 188416734
2020-06-05T01:37:46.229378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 188416743
2020-06-05T01:37:46.229385Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-06-05T01:37:46.229389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.442722Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-05T01:37:46.442754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-05T01:37:46.442814Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-05T01:37:46.463571Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.464893Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.464915Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.465319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-05T01:37:46.515572Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 188416743
2020-06-05T01:37:46.515974Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.516370Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-05T01:37:46.522591Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.522617Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.529113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200604 18:37:46
2020-06-05T01:37:46.529627Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.529722Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.531474Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-06-05T01:37:46.531537Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.531554Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-06-05T01:37:46.531562Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-05T01:37:46.591272Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-06-05T01:37:46.591449Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-06-05T01:43:27.914157Z 224 [Note] Aborted connection 224 to db: '<database>' user: '<username>' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
2020-06-05T01:43:37.458641Z 226 [Note] Aborted connection 226 to db: '<database>' user: '<username>' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-06-05T01:44:16.641164Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-06-05T01:44:16.642888Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 22406 ...
2020-06-05T01:44:16.651991Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652029Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652033Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652036Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652039Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652042Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652439Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-05T01:44:16.652636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-06-05T01:44:16.654861Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 52M, instances = 1, chunk size = 52M
2020-06-05T01:44:16.659698Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-05T01:44:16.661408Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-06-05T01:44:16.686889Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.692320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 188447819
2020-06-05T01:44:16.692336Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 188447828
2020-06-05T01:44:16.692343Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-06-05T01:44:16.692348Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.901379Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-05T01:44:16.901404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-05T01:44:16.901443Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-05T01:44:16.920059Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.921170Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.921187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.921533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-05T01:44:16.971815Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 188447828
2020-06-05T01:44:16.972472Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.972945Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-05T01:44:16.977541Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.977557Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.980940Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.981041Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.983431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200604 18:44:16
2020-06-05T01:44:16.984694Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-06-05T01:44:16.984746Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-06-05T01:44:16.984759Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-06-05T01:44:16.984763Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-05T01:44:17.037645Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-06-05T01:44:17.037799Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-06-05T01:50:26.051180Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-06-05T01:50:26.052918Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 23709 ...
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063292Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063324Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063328Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063349Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063363Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-05T01:50:26.063764Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-06-05T01:50:26.065589Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 52M, instances = 1, chunk size = 52M
2020-06-05T01:50:26.068952Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-05T01:50:26.070314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-06-05T01:50:26.095510Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.102759Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 188478220
2020-06-05T01:50:26.102775Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 188478229
2020-06-05T01:50:26.102783Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-06-05T01:50:26.102787Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.442663Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-05T01:50:26.442688Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-05T01:50:26.442723Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-05T01:50:26.461271Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.462169Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.462182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.462476Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-05T01:50:26.512694Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 188478229
2020-06-05T01:50:26.513183Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.513601Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-05T01:50:26.518699Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.518716Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.520859Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.520984Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.526583Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200604 18:50:26
2020-06-05T01:50:26.528066Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-06-05T01:50:26.528151Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.528172Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-06-05T01:50:26.528180Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-06-05T01:50:26.666477Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-06-05T01:50:26.666681Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-06-05T01:50:26.667545Z 0 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-06-05T01:50:26.667577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-06-05T01:50:28.667748Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2020-06-05T01:50:28.667795Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-06-05T01:50:28.667906Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668640Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668663Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668670Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668677Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668683Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668724Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668734Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668752Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668758Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668764Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668769Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668774Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668779Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668784Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668789Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668794Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668799Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668804Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668809Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668814Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668819Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668824Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668829Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668844Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668860Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668866Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668870Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668876Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668881Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668886Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668891Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668896Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668901Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668906Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-06-05T01:50:28.668988Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-06-05T01:50:28.669176Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-06-05T01:50:28.770277Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-05T01:50:28.770545Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200604 18:50:28
2020-06-05T01:50:30.387663Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 188479684
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389248Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389258Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389262Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389270Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389409Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-06-05T01:50:30.389715Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-06-05T01:50:31.371190Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-06-05T01:50:31.371612Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 23807 ...
```

Hopefully this means the databases have fixed themselves. When I checked on them this morning, they were up for 11 hours, 57 minutes, and 17 seconds.

Comment: Can you get mysql error logs ?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: "Questions" -- total?  Can't be.  "per second"?  per hour"?  What.  Junk!  What do the colors represent for memory?  Which process?  All processes?

Comment: How many cores?  How much RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  Use myisamcheck to fix the "marked as crashed and needs repair" tables.

Plan B:  Don't use ENGINE=MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.  Be sure to adjust key_buffer_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size.